# Script opening multiple Excel instances

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have some VBScript on a Bartender (labeling software) template that accesses an Excel spreadsheet and concatenates data for a given BOM Code in to a string on a report (all data is pulled from the same row). Modifying the spreadsheet or running the script via our application that integrates with Bartender causes many instances of Excel to open and immensely slows down any computer working with the template.

```
Public Function GetData()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open  _
        ("C:\Users\Public\Formulator\Labels\BOMSuffixes.xlsx")

    intRow = 2
    strNames = ""
    genericDescription = ""
    containerWeight = ""
    containerUom = ""

    Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,7).Value = ""
        strNames = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 7).Value
        If InStr(Field("BOM.BOMCode"),strNames) <> 0 Then 
            genericDescription = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 8).Value
            containerWeight = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 9).Value
            containerUom = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 10).Value
        End If

        intRow = intRow + 1
    Loop

    GetData = Field("BOM.BulkQuantity") + " " + Field("BOM.BulkUnits") +
              " (" + CStr(Round(Field("BOM.BulkQuantity")*0.453592, 2) ) +
              " Kg)" +" packed in a " + CStr(containerWeight)  + " " +
              containerUom + " (" + CStr(Round(containerWeight*0.453592, 2) ) +
              " Kg)" + ", " + genericDescription

    objExcel.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid creating and destroying Excel instances over and over you could leave the instance running at the end of the script and (try to) re-attach to an already running instance at the beginning. Only create a new instance if that fails.

```
Public Function GetData()
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err Then
        If Err.Number = 429 Then
            Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        Else
            WScript.Echo Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description
            WScript.Quit 1
        End If
    End If
    On Error Goto 0

    ...

    objExcel.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set objExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

Note however, that with this approach you need some kind of cleanup job to remove the orphaned Excel instance(s) at some point.